# I ran Memtest and got errors. What do I do now?

Tags: windows-7, memtest

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Click to enlarge</sup>

This is my first time running Memtest and I'm not really sure what these errors mean and what to do with them.

Comment: How about a little more details on your hardware?

Comment: generally speaking, if you get errors in memtest, and on a separate run get the same or similar errors, then all you can do is to try replacing the affected stick. It can still be a motherboard issue, but there is no effective way to determine which it is, and its much more likely to be the ram chips themselves.

Comment: **You replace the hardware**

Answer (score 1):

Test each RAM module on its own (remove the other ones) and run memtest again. If you get again any error on a RAM module, replace this broken RAM by a new RAM modules.